# Reading batches of images and training in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to read images in batches here. And train them. When I execute this
it seems to get stuck. There is no progress.
Can anyone spot the problem ? There are no logs being written.

```
def train():
filenames = tf.train.string_input_producer(
    tf.train.match_filenames_once("D:/*.png"))
reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
_, input = reader.read(filenames)
input = tf.Print(input,[input,tf.shape(input),"Input shape"])
input_image = tf.image.decode_png(input, channels=3)
input_image.set_shape([299, 299, 3])

batch = tf.train.batch([input_image],
                       batch_size=5,
                       allow_smaller_final_batch=True,
                       shapes=None,
                       num_threads = 1,
                       capacity = 32,
                       enqueue_many = False,
                       dynamic_pad = False)

init = (tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
    train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('D:/TensorFlow/logs/1/train', sess.graph)
    tf.print(input_image)

    for it in range(2):
        merge = tf.summary.merge_all()
        summary,_, X_batch =  sess.run([merge,input_image,batch])
        writer = train_writer.add_summary(summary)
        _, DiscriminatorLoss = sess.run([D_optimizer, Disc_loss], feed_dict={X: X_batch, Z: samplefromuniformdistribution(5, 100)})
        print (DiscriminatorLoss)
        _, GeneratorLoss = sess.run([G_optimizer, Generate_loss], feed_dict={Z: samplefromuniformdistribution(5, 100)})

    writer.flush()
    writer.close()

coord.request_stop()
coord.join(threads)
sess.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am considering this as an answer until I receive other answers.
The problem I found was related to

```
    filenames = tf.train.string_input_producer(
    tf.train.match_filenames_once("D:/Development_Avecto/TensorFlow/resizedimages/*.png"))
```

The problematic code has a pattern like this.

```
   filenames = tf.train.string_input_producer(
   tf.train.match_filenames_once("D:/*.png"))
```

D:/ has many sub-folders. Was the code trying to search all sub-folders ? That will take a long time to complete.
Checked the source code(https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.7/tensorflow/python/ops/io_ops.py) but didn't identify the read operation.

The sub-folders are searched even though it wasn't evident to me. Test code based on which I came to this conclusion.

```
def readtest():
filenames = tf.train.string_input_producer(
    tf.train.match_filenames_once("D:/FolderWithSubFolders/*.png"))
reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
key, input = reader.read(filenames)

init = (tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
    file, document_tensor = sess.run([key,input])
    print (file)
coord.request_stop()
coord.join(threads)
sess.close()
```